# Configuring modsecurity for nginx

Tags: nginx, apt, mod-security

I have installed nginx using apt-get and now I want to implement modsecurity, a web application firewall on it now. All the solutions and procedures available online show the manual configuration of nginx(using git clone). Can anyone tell me how I can install and configure modsecurity for nginx installed using apt-get on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my online searching goes, it does not seem like anyone provides binary packages for ModSecurity for nginx. Unfortunately you will have to compile them for yourself for now.

Comment: Thanks for this! It would be great if you could help me with my question at https://serverfault.com/questions/896256/nginx-with-modsecurity-does-not-show-php-pages,